# wxpython and share variables between classes

Tags: python, class, wxpython, share, listctrl

I have seen questions where you can share variables between classes -- which I can normally do fairly easily.  However, I am trying to share a variables between a wx.Frame and a custom list control.  Essentially, I have a class with an Editable ListCtrl which uses a dictionary to sort values in a list.  I have normally just made the dictionary a global variable, but I am attempting to completely remove global variables from my code.  How do I reference the dictionary in the ListCtrl class from the wx.Frame class?  below is a snippet of the code.

Thanks!

```
class TMainForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        self.Splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)

        self.Panel1 = wx.Panel(self.Splitter, -1)          
        self.Panel3 = wx.Panel(self.Splitter, -1)

        self.Splitter.SplitVertically(self.Panel1,self.Panel3,450)

        self.Notebook2 = wx.Notebook(self.Panel1, -1)

        # This is the Panel my list is in
        self.List1 = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self.Notebook2, -1)
        self.List1.SetupScrolling()

        # This custom function creates the dictionary for list 1 (labeled self.List1Data)
        self.CreateDictionary()

        # This sets up the listctrl to reference the class EditableListCtrl
        self.List1_list = EditableListCtrl(self.List1,-1,style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
        self.List1_list.InsertColumn(1,'Col 1')
        self.List1_list.InsertColumn(2,'Col 2',format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)

        items = self.List1Data.items()
        index = 0

        for key, data in items:
            self.List1_list.InsertStringItem(index, data[0])
            self.List1_list.SetStringItem(index, 1, data[1])
            self.List1_list.SetItemData(index, key)
            index += 1

        self.List1_list.itemDataMap = self.List1Data

        #...


# In this class i have "List1Data" which is a global variable.  I want to grab self.List1Data
# from the TMainForm class and use it in here (instead of the List1Data global variable).

class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, len(List1Data))
        self.itemDataMap = List1Data
    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self
```

Trying to follow suggested answer below:

```
class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):

    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, len(self.List1Data))
        self.itemDataMap = self.List1Data

    def get_dict(self):
        return self.List1Data

    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self
```

*** EDIT ****

Full runnable code for my issue.  See comment -- I want to be able to reference self.List1Data in TMainForm in the EditableListCtrl class.  Thanks!

```
import os
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class TMainForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        self.Splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)

        self.Panel1 = wx.Panel(self.Splitter, -1)          
        self.Panel3 = wx.Panel(self.Splitter, -1)

        self.Splitter.SplitVertically(self.Panel1,self.Panel3,450)

        self.Notebook2 = wx.Notebook(self.Panel1, -1)
        self.List1 = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self.Notebook2, -1)
        self.List1.SetupScrolling()

        self.UpdateData()

        self.List1_list = EditableListCtrl(self.List1,-1,style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
        self.List1_list.InsertColumn(1,'Col 1')
        self.List1_list.InsertColumn(2,'Col 2',format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)

        self.Update_List()

        self.List1_list.SetColumnWidth(0,-2)
        self.List1_list.SetColumnWidth(1,-2)

        self.Notebook3 = wx.Notebook(self.Panel3, -1)
        self.OptPane = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self.Notebook3, -1)
        self.OptPane.SetupScrolling()

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

    def __set_properties(self): # Set GUI Title and Size

        self.screen_x = 95 * wx.GetDisplaySize()[0]/100
        self.screen_y = 90 * wx.GetDisplaySize()[1]/100

        if wx.GetDisplaySize()[0] < 1920:
            self.Maximize(True)
        else:
            self.SetSize((self.screen_x, self.screen_y))
        self.SetMinSize((1280,768))

        self.SetFocus()


    def __do_layout(self , call_fit = True, set_sizer = True): 

        sizer_22 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_22.Add(self.List1_list,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.List1.SetSizer(sizer_22)

        self.Notebook2.AddPage(self.List1,"List1")

        sizer_P2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_P2.Add(self.Notebook2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.Panel1.SetSizer(sizer_P2)

        sizer_P3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_P3.Add(self.Notebook3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.Panel3.SetSizer(sizer_P3)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.Splitter,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Layout()
        self.Centre()

    def Update_List(self):

        #items = self.List1Data.items()
        items = LD1.items()
        index = 0

        for key, data in items:
            self.List1_list.InsertStringItem(index, str(data[0]))
            self.List1_list.SetStringItem(index, 1, str(data[1]))

            self.List1_list.SetItemData(index, key)
            index += 1

        #self.List1_list.itemDataMap = self.List1Data
        self.List1_list.itemDataMap = LD1

    def UpdateData(self):

        self.List1Data = {}

        self.List1Data[0] = (1,2,3)
        self.List1Data[1] = (4,5,6)

        global LD1
        LD1 = self.List1Data

class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):

    # I want to be able to get self.List1Data from TMainForm here instead of LD1
    #print TMainForm.List1Data

    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):

        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, len(LD1))
        self.itemDataMap = LD1

    def get_dict(self):
        return self.List1Data

    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self

app = wx.App(0)
# Code to Execute File
class TApplication(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):

            wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
            MainForm = TMainForm(None, -1,"")
            self.SetTopWindow(MainForm)

            MainForm.Show()
            return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application = TApplication(0)
    Application.MainLoop()
```

Error when trying to access List1Data in TMainForm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Me/Documents/test.py", line 103, in <module>
    class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
  File "C:/Users/Me/Documents/test.py", line 106, in EditableListCtrl
    print TMainForm.List1Data
AttributeError: type object 'TMainForm' has no attribute 'List1Data'
```

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to write a getter/setter function in wx.Frame subclass.

Comment: can you elaborate?  I have never heard/seen the getter/setter function (I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):

    List1Data={...dictionary item....}

    def __init__(self):

    ### your other methods now
```

You can access your List1Data from any place in other classes just using:

```
EditableListCtrl.List1Data
```

since now, List1Data is the part of your class definition.

Comment: I think I am missing something -- I added my code above to replicate what you posted.  I don't understand how the `get_dict(self)` function actually grabs the `self.List1Data` from `TMainForm`?  I want the `self.List1Data` to be the same across all classes (it is only editable in the `TMainForm` class though)

Comment: Please see the updated answer and it is simple based on your requirement. You just should have List1Data as a part of class definition separately ( not inside any methods, simply). Thus, you can access it using just EditableListCtrl.List1Data.

Comment: what about going the other way (which is what I really want to do)?  Since I define the List1Data in the TMainForm class, I want to essentially do TMainForm.List1Data, but it doesn't allow me to do this (says has no attribute named List1Data).  Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: Can you post the code you ran and also the exact error copied, verbatim?

Comment: I posted some runnable code.  please see edits above.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, it would be great if you can post the exact error you get when you add what I suggested to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42882/discussion-between-jack-of-all-trades-and-mcfly)